# RewriteRule for 'pretty links' not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a link that looks like `https://www.exapmle.com/profile.php?u=8` to look like `https://www.exapmle.com/profile/8`

I have a tried variations of this in `htaccess`:

`RewriteRule ^/profile/([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1`

`RewriteRule  ^/profile/([0-9]+)\.html /profile.php?u=$1`

I don't know what i am doing wrong, the links don't change and I'm not getting any errors either

Comment: Show your full htaccess rules you are using for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(\d+)(?:\.html)?/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```